# Can you send a post to a website back to back with TIdHTTP?

Tags: delphi, http, post, indy

I've got a program that acts as an interface between a web server and a user which allows the user to upload files to the web server. When the user clicks "Upload" it takes the information from a list view and sends it to the website, the first http.Post is for the actual file and the second is for the meta-data I am storing about it.

When I comment out the first Post statement it works fine and actually posts the data, but it doesn't seem to get any of the params for the second one when they're both in there. It also works when I run the script in a web browser with the values in Param.

UFile is a record containing the file meta-data.

```
  IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
  http := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  http.IOHandler := IOHandler;
  Param := TStringList.Create;
  DataParams := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
  Stream := TStringStream.Create('');
  DebugStream := TStringStream.Create('');

  Param.Add('serial='+UFile.Serial);
  Param.Add('filename='+UFile.Name);
  Param.Add('filepath='+'\'+UFile.Serial+'\'+IntToStr(UFile.PatchID));
  Param.Add('patchid='+IntToStr(UFile.PatchID));
  Param.Add('patchnotes='+UFile.PatchNotes);
  Param.Add('earliestversion='+UFile.EarliestVersion);
  Param.Add('latestversion='+UFile.LatestVersion);
  Param.Add('date='+DateToStr(UFile.Date));
  Param.Add('execaftersend='+BoolToStr(UFile.ExecAfterSend));

  DataParams.AddFile('file', UFile.FilePath, 'application/octet-stream');

  try
    http.Post('http://example.com/postFile.php', DataParams, Stream);
    ShowMessage(Stream.DataString);
    http.Post('http://example.com/uploadFiles.php', Param, DebugStream);
    ShowMessage(DebugStream.DataString);
    for J := 0 to Pred(Param.Count) do
      DebugStrings := DebugStrings + '&' + Param.Strings[J];
    ShowMessage(DebugStrings);
  except
    on E: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
    begin
      ShowMessage('Error code:' + IntToStr(E.ErrorCode));
    end
  end;
```

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't seem to get any of the params"? Does the server receive a TCP connection? Does it receive an HTTP request for the given URL? What happens in your program?

Comment: @RobKennedy The DebugStream.DataString returns errors of "undefined variable on line...etc" for all the requested parameters.

Comment: It's seems to be a php error. Check out thru a browser if it works.

Comment: @GregM. Works fine in a browser, using the same parameters that are shown with the Param strings.

Comment: Send your requests to [RequestBin](http://requestb.in/) from your program and from the browser, and compare the results. The differences will give clues about what's wrong.

Comment: Well, it seems to me that the content you send thru IdHTTPClient is not exactly the same as the browser. You should check if there's nothing missing or different with a tcpdump (wireshark is a nice tool)

Comment: @GregM. The cool thing is, I've already done that, and just re-checked, and it's the same.

Comment: Is there any session information that must be existing before doing this request ? In fact, it's hard to tell as we can't see the server script and the context of the error. The service supplier can't help you diagnose the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

While this doesn't really solve the problem with doing two Posts, it does allow you to upload a file with other data, which is why I was doing two posts to begin with.

Use TIdMultiPartFormDataStream and add your file AddFile, and add any other data with AddFormField.

Example:

```
  DataParams.AddFile('file', UFile.FilePath, 'application/octet-stream');
  DataParams.AddFormField('serial', UFile.Serial);
  DataParams.AddFormField('filename', UFile.Name);
```